# Prove which application is used for opening log files: assoc and ftype seem unreliable on Windows-10

Tags: windows-10, command-line, file-association, windows-server-2016, file-extension

My customer has a problem with logfiles, which become too large: on their PC (windows-Server 2016) Notepad.exe is used as the application for opening such files. I've altered this to Notepad++.exe, solving the issue.

Now I would like to inform them about this, using simple commandlines for supporting what I did. So, as I have the same settings on my computer (Windows-10), I decided to use `assoc` and `ftype` for this. To my surprise, this is what I get (on my Windows-10 computer):

```
Prompt>C:\Users\DDM>assoc | findstr /I "log"
...
.log=txtfile
...

Prompt>ftype | findstr /I "txtfile"
txtfile=%SystemRoot%\system32\NOTEPAD.EXE %1
```

Although my computer uses Notepad++ for opening such files (just like the customer's PC) => to the command's result seems to be wrong!

Which commandline commands can I use for proving to the customer that Notepad.exe has been replaced by Notepad++.exe for opening "*.log" files?

Thanks

**Edit**
I just realised that I only modified the file extension association for my own user, not for all users, while `assoc`/`ftype` gives that association for the entire PC. So my question becomes, does such a command exist per user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just found following registry entry:

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\...
...\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.log\UserChoice
```

(split over two lines for readability reasons, the correct syntax contains `Windows\CurrentVersion`)

So this would mean that, in order to show the file association for the current user, I can use this commandline command:

```
Prompt>reg query "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\...
...\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.log\UserChoice"
```

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\...
...\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.log\UserChoice
    ProgId    REG_SZ    Applications\notepad++.exe
    Hash      REG_SZ    d0CsAhT8BLU=
```

Can anybody confirm this is correct?